# Issue while inserting items in zero th index on UICollectionViewController with inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, chat

I am developing a chat conversation UI using `UICollectionViewController`, initially having 20 items in **collectionViewController**.

When I did scroll to top.

```
if scrollView.contentOffset.y == - 44 { /* Inserting 10 items at zero th position in collectionView */ }
```

I will insert 10 items at `IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)`

So will have a total of 30 items in CollectionView.

At this time I got some UI animation issue and collection view was scrolled to top.

e.g actual items are 0,1,2,3...19

now I am inserting at zeroth index so items like 29,28,27,...20,0,1,2,3...19

I hope you understand.

[image: example gif]

my issue is when my collection view is showing 0,1,2,3 at top I am inserting 29,28,27,...20
but collection view won't scroll to up or down. It has to show same 0,1,2,3 like (silently insert items at top and don't change any ui)

Like WhatsApp chat - fetching old messages while scrolling to top.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand, but you can try this:

```
 self.collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0,y:0), animated: true)
```

after your `insertItem` method populate your datasource.

Comment: Have to show inserted items like previously loaded datas. with out animation